# share photo from Camera Roll via my app

Tags: iphone, camera, ios6, shared-libraries

i want to develop a app that can share image to social network, it work well but i want my app have some advance function

i see that in ios6, it can share image from photo library by tap sharing button

now i want my app in the list app in share screen, how can i do that ?

[image]

```
- (void) loadMoreData

{
   [self requestServerGetTimeline];
}

- (void) btnImageClicked:(NSString *)photoId
{
    DetailImageController *detailImageController = [[DetailImageController alloc] initwithPhotoId:photoId withNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailImageController animated:YES];
    [detailImageController release];
}

- (void) btnUsernameClicked:(NSString *)userId
{
    MeshUserInformationController *detailUserController = [[MeshUserInformationController alloc] initWithNavigation:self.navigationController withUserId:userId];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailUserController animated:YES];
    [detailUserController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure UIActivityView controller of Photos app but you can configure and make your own activities for your apps.